# PHP str_replace with a changeable part

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I am trying to str_replace a string like *(infobox tbs7)* with a string like *something with tbs7*. But i want it to work even when the *tbs7* is something else. I have defined *(infobox $)* and *something with $*, but the $ should be be anything.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regular Expressions with preg_grep:

```
$source = '(infobox tbs7)';
$target = 'something with $2';
$pattern = '/^(\(infobox )(.*)(\))$/i';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $target, $source);
```

The regex pattern 'splits' the source string into three pieces:

```
'(infobox '           -> $1
'anything in between' -> $2
')'                   -> $3
```

and $2 is used in the replacement string to indicate what to replace.

Comment: Thanks, but i also wanted to find the *(infobox)* thingy in a bunch of text. If i put text containing the infobox *and* some other text, it just outputs the $source.

Comment: Maybe you should add some examples. It is not really clear to me, what the source string can look like.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the pattern `\binfobox \S+` with `infobox` followed by the replacement word:

```regex
$input = "Here is infobox tbs7 and other things.";
$output = preg_replace("/\binfobox \S+/", "infobox abc", $input);
echo $output;  // Here is infobox abc and other things.
```

Comment: Almost there! I would need the code to output *tbs7* (no matter what follows the infobox) as a variable to make this code work as i want to.